# Grosseria na tradução do Nosso Modelo > Edição

Tags: suporte, tradução

[Em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), ênfase minha:

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, **this may not be** the site for you.

[Aqui no SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> [...], este site não é para você

Sugiro:

> [...], pode ser que este não seja um site para você

Comment: acho que tá bom assim, não acho grosseria

Comment: @Math, bom, no fundo eu também acho que não, mas acreditava que a etiqueta inglesa/brasileira eram muito semelhantes... Agora mesmo acho que o estilo é germânico/hispânico: seco e direto, sem muitas "desculpas" ou "maybes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grosseria ou não, está impreciso em relação ao inglês. Duas alternativas mais precisas:

- [...], talvez este site não seja para você.
- [...], este site pode não ser para você.

Ou queremos passar uma ideia diferente aqui no SOpt? Este site *também é* para quem não quer ter seus posts editados?

Comment: Concordo plenamente

Comment: Espero que não :) Mas é engraçado que as vezes recebemos recomendações da SE que não contra o que está escrito na Central de Ajuda :D Se eles querem mudar, façam o dever de casa primeiro. Não vou lembrar de nada agora, apenas quando eu leio algo assim é que dá uma luz.

Comment: Minha impressão era que Ingleses e Lusos compartilhavam esse jeitinho doce e hipócrita de dizer sorrindo *"Ah, não, infelizmente, pode ser que este não seja um site para você"*, quando no fundo a mensagem é *"Vai embora daqui que sua atitude não é bem-vinda"*.